# HTTP Request Failed - Google Maps Geocoding/HostGator

Tags: php, mysql, http, null, request

Help would be appreciated on this. I have a txt/xml list of physical addresses that I pass through a Google Maps geocoding script but have been running into a problem where the address spits out a null value on the coord_lat and my MySQL database rejects this. The error I receive is an HTTP request failed so I believe it is problem where the Google Maps is rejecting my connection and returning a null value which then breaks my script/database. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this  connection and/or add something to the script? I am currently using HostGator as my hosting service.

Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?key=AIzaSyBmT9F_ixjLlW8oDiYVqgHqt1888&output=xml&q=xxx+here) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /includes/func.php on line 297
{"status":"Failed","data":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'coord_lat' cannot be null"}
ErrorSyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
function get_lat_long($address, $zipcode) {
    if(strlen($zipcode) == 4){
        $zipcode = '0' . $zipcode;
        //echo $zipcode . "\n";
    }   



    $apikey = "AIzaSyBmT9F_ixjLlW8oDiYVqgHqt1888";
    $geourl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?key=" . $apikey . "&output=xml&q=" . urlencode($address) . "+" . urlencode($zipcode);
    //echo $geourl;
    //echo "<br>";

    // Grab XML content using $geourl
    $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));

    $xml = file_get_contents($geourl, false, $context);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);


    //Parse the lat and long from the XML
    $Lat = $xml->results->result->locations->location->displayLatLng->latLng->lat;
    //echo $Lat;
    $Lng = $xml->results->result->locations->location->displayLatLng->latLng->lng;
    //echo $Lng;


    //Return
    if($Lng && $Lat) {
        return array('lat'=>$Lat,
                     'lng'=>$Lng
                     );          
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use google maps v3 what you are using is v2  i think and its not working anymore

```
            $Address = urlencode($Address);
                $url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=egypt&sensor=false';
                $source = file_get_contents($url);
                $obj = json_decode($source);
                $lat = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $lng = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: I believe you may be right. I noticed in the $url that egypt is included. How would I add my urelencode `. urlencode($address) . "+" . urlencode($zipcode);` to this url?

Comment: try this : 
json?components=country:us|postal_code:zipcode&sensor=false